# Ginger beer fermentation produces thick, white foam, becomes viscous

Tags: ginger-beer, problems

I’m making a batch of ginger beer from a bug. 5l water, 400g white sugar.
Within just over a day, the fermentation started foaming heavily. The foam has a consistency and taste of egg whites beaten for a merengue. The rest of the liquid is turning thick and viscous.

What’s happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an undesirable bacteria / yeast combo. Try again with a new or known good ginger bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infection from pediococci. They produce long carbohydrate chains that tangle together, which results in this viscous consistency. It's not harmful, it just feels gross. Reportedly, after a few weeks/months, a fermented product will return to normal consistency as the carbs making up the goop get broken down but I've never personally tested this claim. Whenever I get a pediococcus infection, I toss away whatever product happens to be infected and start a new batch.

Comment: Thanks! The viscosity did decrease a few days later - but somehow this batch ended up with very low carbonation. All perfectly drinkable, still.